# Multiple feeds with MWFeedParser, help with code

Tags: iphone, xcode, rss, feed

I currently have this code but it leaks because I don't know how to release feed parser object this many times, so I need help with memory management or some other way to feed multiple feeds with it.

Code:

```
for (NSString *imePredmeta in [Data variables].mojiPredmeti) {
        NSString *link = [[Data variables].rss objectForKey: imePredmeta];
        NSURL *feedURL = [NSURL URLWithString: link];
        feedParser = [[MWFeedParser alloc] initWithFeedURL:feedURL];
        feedParser.delegate = self;
        feedParser.feedParseType = ParseTypeFull; // Parse feed info and all items
        feedParser.connectionType = ConnectionTypeAsynchronously;
        [feedParser parse];        
    }
```

Dealloc:

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [formatter release];
    [parsedItems release];
    [itemsToDisplay release];
    [feedParser release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

And initWithFeedUrl from MWFeedParser code is:

```
- (id)initWithFeedURL:(NSURL *)feedURL {
    if ((self = [self init])) {

        // Check if an string was passed as old init asked for NSString not NSURL
        if ([feedURL isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
            feedURL = [NSURL URLWithString:(NSString *)feedURL];
        }

        // Remember url
        self.url = feedURL;

    }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way would be to add them to an array, and then in `dealloc` release that array.

```
// declare an iVar in your header file
NSMutableArray *feeds;

// instantiate the array, but release it first as you may call your method more 
// than once
if (feeds) {
    [feeds release];
}
feeds = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (NSString *imePredmeta in [Data variables].mojiPredmeti) {
    ...
    // after calling parse on the feed, add it to the array and then release it. 
    // Objects added to an array are retained by the array so this is safe
    [feedParser parse];
    [feeds addObject:feedParser]; // <-- Add parser to array
    [feedParser release]; // <-- Release parser 
}

// then in your dealloc simply release the array, which will in-turn release all 
// the parser objects it contains
- (void)dealloc {
    [formatter release];
    [parsedItems release];
    [itemsToDisplay release];
    [feeds release]; // <-- Release feeds array
    // I've removed the call to release feedParser as it's already been released
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: Yeah, exactly like that :) Just remember to remove the `[feedParser release];` line from your `dealloc` or you'll generate a crash.

Comment: Ok, seems there are no leaks! :)
But one more problem, when the table is empty (no feeds) and when I click refresh, the app crashes, how to solve this?
Is it because of the [feedParser release]; because it doesn't exist then, I think?

Comment: Can you put the code for the whole refresh method up on Pastebin?

Comment: Remove this line `[feedParser stopParsing];` ... If the feeds array already exists, when you call `[feeds release];` it'll release all stored parsers which will obviously halt their parsing as they'll no longer be around.

Comment: OK, doesn't crash anymore :)
But still there is one more leak to solve, and my project is finished! :)

Ok, I start profiling in Instruments with no objects in [Data variables].mojiPredmeti where the RSS urls are, I click refresh, everything i ok, I add rss in settings (add object to mojiPredmeti), refresh the RSS, everything ok again, feeds load ok, add another rss, still ok, but when I remove all  objects in mojiPredmeti (remove all rss urls) and click refresh I get a leak: http://i52.tinypic.com/fxfos8.png 

And btw, thanks for all your help so far :)

Comment: Whilst I'm happy to continue to help you, since we've fixed the issue specifically related to your question could you please accept my answer?

Comment: In Instruments, in the side tab under **Call Tree** click *Invert Call Tree* and *Hide System Libraries*. It should now show you the method name where the leak originates from. If you double-click the method name it should jump you to the exact line of code that creates the object that leaks.

Comment: In my app I have two rss readers, one that reads always the same url, and the other one, for which I are urls in [Data variables].mojiPredmeti

In first I don't have any leaks, but in second I get this:
http://i56.tinypic.com/efs8rd.png

Comment: Can you post your code for the delegate methods `feedParser:didParseFeedItem:` and `feedParserDidFinish:`

Comment: I honestly can't see from your code what's leaking. If you double-click on the leak in Instruments, which line of code does it highlight?

Comment: I'm uploading the video file I've recorded so you can see, I will post link as soon as it's uploaded on media fire

Comment: Ok, in the video you'll see that in the beginning there are no feeds, but there are no leaks either when I refresh, and later when I remove feeds there is a leak, and also I double clicked every leak so you can se the code, here it is: http://www.wupload.com/file/151417872/Instruments.mov

And sorry for the background music, forgot to turn it off... ^^

Comment: I'm really not sure what's causing the leaks, it's certainly not obvious from the video. The only thing I can suggest is to wrap the entire method in an `NSAutoReleasePool` which may help though I offer no guarantees.

Comment: Tried it, same thing, damn it, doesn't make any sense :S
As soon as I hit refresh, leaks come out, and only if I remove all rss... :S